# Retrieve Email address of file owner permission?(apps domain)

Tags: google-drive-api

I have the owner permission of a certain file. I wan't to share this file around in the domain. For this in need to impersonate the owner. To impersonate a user I use a service account, but I still need a ServiceAccountUser. The serviceAccountUser is the email adress of the owner.

I can read the owner name from the permission but I don't know how to get his email adress.
I got suggested to use the profile API to gather this information, but I was wondering if there isn't a way to do this with the drive api.

How can I retrieve the Email adress of the file owner permission?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that with Drive API, until Google hopefully changes it.

You will have to use the old Document List API and its AclFeed to retrieve the emails of your users

Comment: Can I set a ServiceAccountUser who is allowed to do anything?

Comment: This is not confirmed by me but i don't think this will work, as it is possible to share files with someone not in your domain. So even a service account won't have the right to see such emails. I dont even think a service account can see emails from inside the domain, even if this seems logical

Comment: I can't figure out how the doclist api works in java :/ It's completly different from the drive api.

Comment: Indeed... And harder to use/understand than drive API

Comment: Pff I'm using the provisioning api to retrieve the name but it only gives me this:entry.getName().getGivenName() + " " + entry.getName()... This way I construct the ownername. Thats very hacky and doesn't always work is there a java tutorial on how to use the docslist api?

Comment: I figured out how the doclist api works it works like the provisioning api. But still so much work just to get the owners email address.